# 3D picking in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am making a Minecraft style game, with 3D array of blocks divided into chunks. But then i need to check what block player is pointing at to perform world modification. This is what i've come up with so far:

```
    private Block getBlockLookedAt(EntityPlayer ep) {


        double px = ep.getPosition().x;
        double py = ep.getPosition().y;
        double pz = ep.getPosition().z;

        float pPitch = ep.getPitch()*-1;
        float pYaw = ep.getYaw()*-1;

        double searchRadius = 6;

        double targetX = searchRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pYaw))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pPitch));
        double targetY = searchRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pYaw))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pPitch));
        double targetZ = searchRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pPitch));
        //System.out.println("=");
        //System.out.println(px + "," + py + "," + pz);
        //System.out.println(targetX + "," + targetY + "," + targetZ);
        //System.out.println("=");
        for(double i = 0; i<searchRadius; i+=0.01){
            targetX = i * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pYaw))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pPitch));
            targetY = i * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pYaw))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pPitch));
            targetZ = i * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pPitch));
            int bx = (int)Math.ceil(targetX+px);
            int by = (int)Math.ceil((targetY*-1)+py);
            int bz = (int)Math.ceil(targetZ+pz);
            System.out.println(bx + "," + by + "," + bz + "," + getBlock(bx,by,bz).getID());
            if(getBlock(bx,by,bz).getID()!=0)return getBlock(bx,by,bz);
        }



        return Block.air;
    }
```

What i am doing here, is using spherical coordinates, and adding 0.01 to checking radius to check if there is block different than air in range. Although that doesn't seem to work (it always returns air, i need to be inside the blocks for it to detect the other blocks)
Anybody has the solution, or perhaps a better way to do it?

PS. I've read schabby's tutorial, and as far as i understand it properly, it doesnt check for Z axis, so that is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
double searchRadius = 0;
...
for(double i = 0; i<searchRadius; i+=0.01){
    ...
}
return Block.air;
```

Try a `searchRadius` that's greater than zero.

Comment: I made searchRadius 6, although it still only outputs 0's.